# Invert a matrix in place with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very big matrix that I want to invert. `numpy.linalg.inv` works great but is it also possible to do this in place (without allocating a new matrix)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  However scipy.linalg.inv gives you roughly this functionality with the `overwrite_a` option:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.inv.html#scipy.linalg.inv

But why do you want to invert it?  This is almost always the wrong thing to do.
http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/

Instead, use numpy.linalg.solve and provide stack all your independent vectors into a single matrix so that you can solve them all at one go.  Cheaper, and better numerical stability.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html#numpy.linalg.solve

Comment: The `overwrite_a` option seems to be not available in the [NumPy function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html)? And yes, I really want to invert the matrix as I need the solution for every single vector (I want to cache the result and provide fast access to the single vectors of the inverse later).

Comment: @Michael Right: the numpy function does not provide this option.

Out of curiosity, what will you do with the vectors drawn from the inverse?

Comment: I am working with kind of an input-output model. A column in the inverse describes the amounts of products that are totally required to produce a single unit of the product that is represented by the respective column. These amounts are used to scale other matrices and indicators to allow supply chain analysis. When there is a request to calculate a set of products, I just jump into the pre-calculated inverse, get the respective columns, and scale them for the results. The inverse is stored on disk and the columns are loaded via memory mapping which is super-fast…